# How to stop infinite looping the output?

Tags: c

I have code with a function that returns the biggest digit from a number. The requirement is to enter numbers until something that is not a number is entered. When something that isn't a number is entered, the program is supposed to stop, but in my case it just starts an infinite loop that prints the last result that the function returned. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int maxDigit(int n){
    int temp = n, maxDig = 0;
    while(temp){
        int digit = temp % 10;
        if(digit > maxDig){
            maxDig = digit;
        }
        temp /= 10;
    }
    return maxDig;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 1, broj;
    while(n){
    if(scanf("%d", &broj)); 
    printf("%d\n", maxDigit(broj)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: that's a lot of n's all over the place.  n declared in main() is only in scope in main() and never changes.

Comment: Think about under which condition `while(n)` would *stop*.

Comment: *"I keep doing the same thing over-and-over and nothing changes -- what's up with that?"* After 1 Million iterations -- what is the value of `n`? Why hasn't it changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the return value of `scanf` to see if you read a valid integer, and you can use `break` to terminate your loop.  The `n` variable in your `main` function just had a constant value so I got rid of it, and cleaned up the function in a few other ways.  Here is my resulting code:

```
...
int main() {
  while (1) {
    int input;
    if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1) { break; }
    printf("%d\n", maxDigit(input)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Alternative for OP, declare `int input;` above the read-loop and control the read-loop with `while (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) { ... }`. Exact same except for the scope of `input`.. Though, generally, the version in the answer provides a solid blueprint for all input with `scanf()`. Loop continually until the user provides the required input and handle any error that arises, checking the return for matching-failure as well as manual `EOF`.

Comment: That works. Thanks :)

Comment: @БојанВасилевски Great!  Please click the checkmark to accept my answer.